# How long does it take to use an alchemist's extract?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

Each spell has it's own casting time, e.g. [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) takes 1 full round and [Burst of Speed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burst-of-speed) takes a swift action.

On the other hand,

> Drinking a potion or using an oil is a standard action

[Extracts are described](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Alchemy-Su-) as

> **In many ways, they behave like spells in potion form,** and as such their effects can be dispelled by effects like dispel magic using the alchemist's level as the caster level. Unlike potions, though, extracts can have powerful effects and duplicate spells that a potion normally could not.

So how long does consuming an extract take? I'm inclined to believe that it takes just as long as the spell does to cast (e.g. a full round to Enlarge Person, only a swift for Burst of Speed) but I'd love to know if this is ever clarified in the rules or a FAQ that I've missed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

quoted from [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist)(d20pfsrd, same page as you link to), quoting [this](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qv2)(pathfinder FAQ):

> ### What kind of action is it to use an extract, mutagen, or throw a bomb?
>
> It is a standard action to use an extract, mutagen, or throw a bomb. This action includes retrieving the necessary materials from the alchemist's supplies, in the same manner as retrieving a material component is included in the act of spellcasting.

This means some things take longer than normal to do via extract, and many things take less time than normal.  This is in many ways balanced against other deficiencies in the alchemist class, and, as you point out, makes sense with the rules for quaffing potions.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the authoritative text I was looking for. I normally wait a while before accepting an answer but is one's quite cut and dry.

Answer (score -3):

It's worth noting that an alchemist can get buffed about 8 times in a round operating off their own class features. Accelerated Drinker (trait) for a potion drunk as move action, standard action consumption of a combined extract (although mutagen is likely preferable here), an immediate action for another combined extract storedstored via Delayed Consumption (which itself restricts the full this trick to higher levels), and then more potions applied via poisoner's gloves wielded by their (improved) tumor familiar.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.